# Can I hide a dd-mon-yyyy component from Oracle SQL DATE when I display the data and get only hh:mm:ss am format?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am inserting data into an SQL table. I needed to separate columns for date, and time. I defined it as:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment (
    "Date" DATE,
    "Time" DATE);
```

and then I inserted values:

```
INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES ('10/Jan/2020', to_date('9:00:00 AM','hh:mi:ss am');
INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES ('15/Feb/2020', to_date('10:00:00 AM','hh:mi:ss am');
```

However, when I tried to display the values, all of the "Time" values were equal "1-Dec-2020", but the sorting based on the "Time" worked properly. Can I hide this "dd-mon-yyyy" from displaying, or remove it from the dataset?

This is how the output is displayed, I want to see my hh:mm:ss am format:

[image: Screenshot showing Date and Time columns with DD-MMM-YY format]

Unfortunately, I am working on Oracle SQL, so I cannot use TIME function.

Comment: What about `TO_CHAR("Date", 'hh:mi:ss am')`?

Comment: I do not have it in one column, I have two separate columns with date dd-mon-yyyy and other with hh:mi:ss am. I guess that SQL assumed that sysdate needs to be inserted for these hh:mi:ss am values, that is why I cannot get a proper output from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using strings and check constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment (
    "Date" DATE,
    "Time" VARCHAR2(8),
    CHECK chk_appointment_date (date = trunc(date)),
    CHECK chk_appointment_time (regexp_like(time, '^[0-2][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]')
);
```

Otherwise, just put the values in a single column and generate the date part values:

```
create table appointment (
    date_time date,
    the_date date generated always as (trunc(date_time)) virtual,
    the_time varchar(8) generated always (to_char(date_time, 'HH24:MI:SS'))
)
```

Comment: Virtual columns did the job. If I want to order by the_time, then I apply to_date(the_time,"hh:mm:ss am") and it works!

Answer (score 1):

It is a **very** bad idea to store date/time as strings - don't do that!

Use proper `DATE` data type and format the output according to your needs (or use VIRTUAL COLUMN as proposed by Gordon):

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment ( DateTime DATE);

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES 
   (to_date('10/Jan/2020 9:00:00 AM','dd/Mon/YYYY hh:mi:ss am', 'nls_date_language = american'));
INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES 
   (to_date('15/Feb/2020 10:00:00 AM','dd/Mon/YYYY hh:mi:ss am', 'nls_date_language = american'));

SELECT TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'hh:mi:ss am')
from Appointment;
```

Comment: Is there any way to store them in separate columns?  For example, if I want to ORDER BY hh:mi:ss of the appointment, without taking care about the dd-mon-yyyy component?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DateTime, 'hh24:mi:ss')` or a virtual column

Answer (score 1):

> Can I hide this "dd-mon-yyyy" from displaying

Yes, You can hide it. I would suggest not to use the `TIME` column alone, It is built-in with the date in oracle. but if this is required for you then You need to use the `TO_CHAR` as follows:

```
SELECT "Date", TO_CHAR("Time",'hh:mi:ss AM') from your_table;
```

I would have created the single column in the table with data type date and whenever needed, I can use `TO_CHAR(DATECOLUMN, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` for date and `TO_CHAR(DATECOLUMN, 'hh:mi:ss AM')` for time